# VBA: SaveCopyAs not password protecting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template, that I copy data into, then suse `SaveCopyAs` to save it down in a different location. I want to start adding a it each time. However all that happens is it saves it down in new location without password.

Attached below is the code, the reason I use the extra (unnecessary) `.Open` is due to the fact I could not find a way to do it just using `SaveCopyAs`

```
Option Explicit 
Sub SaveCopyAs_password()

    Dim passdate As String
    Dim wb, wbresults As Workbook

    passdate = "hello"

    Workbooks.Open ("R:\Macros\pre\Mealplan.xlsx")

    Set wbresults = Workbooks("Mealplan")
    wbresults.SaveCopyAs ("R:\Macros\post\Mealplan.xlsx")

    Workbooks.Open ("R:\Macros\post\Mealplan.xlsx")
    Workbooks("Mealplan.xlsx").Activate

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Password:=passdate

    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use parentheses around parameters for procedures/functions when you are not retrieving a returned value, it will only cause errors.

Comment: And I'm quite sure you cannot open two documents named the same in Excel, even if they are in different folders.

Comment: Please re-read what you've written and use the [edit] link to fill in the missing information/typos in the first paragraph. It's not clear what you want to add. The code is also not clear. You "dim" wb0 and wbT but these are not used in the code. On the other hand, a wbresults and wb are instantiated but not declared. Put the line `Option Explicit` at the top of the code page to help avoid "stray" variables that can make code unpredictable and for others un-reproducible.

Comment: Have edited the above. It is not an issue with opening the file, as it does save in new location and then open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Simple code will work for you:

```
Sub SaveCopyAs_password()

    Dim passdate As String
    Dim wbresults As Workbook

    passdate = "hello"

    FileCopy "R:\Macros\pre\Mealplan.xlsx", "R:\Macros\post\Mealplan.xlsx"

    Set wbresults = Workbooks.Open("R:\Macros\post\Mealplan.xlsx")
    wbresults.SaveAs Password:=passdate

    wbresults.Close

End Sub
```

---

## Another Way:

```
Sub SaveCopyAs_password()

    Dim passdate As String
    Dim wbresults As Workbook

    passdate = "hello"

    Set wbresults = Workbooks.Open("R:\Macros\pre\Mealplan.xlsx")

    wbresults.SaveAs Filename:="R:\Macros\post\Mealplan.xlsx", Password:=passdate

    wbresults.Close

End Sub
```

Run this Macro from any other workbook other than the 2 used in Macro.